# SQL Server : query correlation from two tables

Tags: sql-server, select

I have two tables that I am trying to correlate data from:

`Tasklist`:

```
Hostname    PID     Process       Module
-----------------------------------------------
Host1       1       sample.exe    sample.dll
Host2       4       sample2.exe   sample2.dll
Host5       11      sample5.exe   sample.dll
```

and

`Netstat`:

```
Hostname    PID    Address    .... (many other columns I don't care about)
------------------------------
Host9       8      10.10.10.10
Host2       67     78.66.44.22
Host8       78     54.22.11.33
Host1       1      77.33.22.11
```

What I want to do is return everything from the tasklist table for lines in which the Hostname and PID from the Tasklist table are also found in the Netstat table. So in this case, it would return the first row from the Tasklist table since Host1 and PID 1 exist in Netstat.

I'm fairly new to SQL and don't really know how to do this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Apply join on pid and hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use join on both tables to get matching values from both tables but as you need values from `tasklist`. You can do something like this,

```
      Select tasklist.*,netstat.address 
      From tasklist join netstat
       On tasklist.pid = netstat.pic and tasklist.hostname = netstat.hostname
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Appreciate the help - one last thing... Is there any way for me to also get the address from the netstat table? It's not necessary but would make my life a lot easier. I understand that this would be returning things from two different tables which I don't know if that's possible? Would I have to use INSERT INTO and create a new table with the results? Thanks again!

Comment: You rock!! Thanks - very helpful and saves me a lot of time.

Comment: No need to do anything else just select the columns u need from both tables in select.I have updated the answer for your requirements