# Access query to get rows for a range of times (disregarding date)

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, ms-access, time

I have this table :

```
Number   Fall Time                     Accuracy 
-------------------------------------------------------
1        01/01/2010 10:00:00           0.3   
2        15/03/2011 10:30:00           0.123   
3        31/01/1994 11:00:00           0.2
```

I want the fall time between 10:00:00 - 10:59:59 **(Don't care about day/month/year)**

I want this result :

```
      Accuracy 
-----------------
      0.3   
      0.123
```

My try :

```
"SELECT Accuracy FROM Ikun WHERE PARSE(Fall_Time AS time) >= '10:00:00' AND PARSE(Fall_Time AS time) <= '10:59:59')"
```

The error : Missing operator syntax error in the query.
Thanks in advance, Ben.

Comment: Access?  Or MySQL?  Your title says Access and your tag says MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HOUR` function. Ref. [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)

```
SELECT Accuracy 
FROM Ikun 
WHERE HOUR(Fall_Time) = 10
```

Comment: It doesn't work too. It makes the same error as I wrote. Please help.